# How to get original texture from SpriteAtlas to use in a shader as alpha mask?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, shaderlab

I have an issue, and i need help to resolve it.

I am try to colorize some parts of sprite dynamically by custom shader and additional textures as masks. It is not a problem and i solve it easy.

Screen for better understanding:

[image]

This is real implementation and color blending for thirs image was realized by shader, sprite and mask.

But I am been forced to use atlases for saving RAM cause have to many sprites to load at the same time (3 states and 5 directions for each of varyous units). And this was caused problems. When i try to do this in edit mode (by using ExecuteInEditMode) all works fine. But when i press "play" button, all breaks down.

How it's look like:

[image]

As i understand, problem is that when I press "play" atlas was builded. So when I get sprite from it I get it susseccfully. But when I try to get texture from Sprite for seting it to Shader I have got big texture (full atlas). Shader do not know nothing about actual position on this sheet for cheking is pixel need to colorizing.

So my question are: how can i get "small" texture from sprite to set it to shader?

How I set "mask" to shader:

```
public void UpdateMask(Texture tex)
{
    //Debug.LogFormat("UpdateMask {0}", tex);
    m_SRenderer.GetPropertyBlock(m_SpriteMbp);
    m_SpriteMbp.SetTexture("_Mask", tex);
    m_SRenderer.SetPropertyBlock(m_SpriteMbp);
}
```

Some shader's pieces:

```
Properties 
{
    [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Sprite Texture (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    [PerRendererData] _Mask("Alpha (A)", 2D)  = "white" {}

    _FriendlyColor("FriendlyColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _EnemyColor("EnemyColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _NeutralColor("NeutralColor", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

    _Intencity("BlendingIntencity", Range(0, 1)) = 0.5
    [PerRendererData] _IsFriendly("IsFriendly", Float) = 0

    [PerRendererData] _IsHighlight("Outline", Range(0, 1)) = 0
    [PerRendererData] _HighlightColor("Outline Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
}


fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR
{
    fixed4 mainTex = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
    fixed4 alphaMask = tex2D(_Mask, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
    fixed4 output;
    fixed4 blendColor;

    if (alphaMask.a > 1.0e-6)
    {
        if (_IsFriendly == 4)
        {
            blendColor = fixed4(_NeutralColor.r, _NeutralColor.g, _NeutralColor.b, alphaMask.r);
        }
        else
        {
            if (_IsFriendly == 1)
            {
                blendColor = fixed4(_FriendlyColor.r, _FriendlyColor.g, _FriendlyColor.b, alphaMask.r);                     
            }
            else
            {
                blendColor = fixed4(_EnemyColor.r, _EnemyColor.g, _EnemyColor.b, alphaMask.r);
            }
        }                   
        output = BlendOverelay(mainTex, blendColor * _Intencity);
    }   
    else
    {
        output = mainTex;
        output.rgb *= output.a;
    }

    if (_IsHighlight != 0)
    {
        fixed4 blendedColor = BlendAdditive(output, _HighlightColor);
        blendedColor.a = output.a;
        blendedColor.rgb *= output.a;
        output = blendedColor;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the sprite renderer where its position in the atlas is and how large the atlas is, so that it can convert the `IN.texcoord` UV in atlas space to the corresponding UV in sprite space. Then, you can sample from the alpha map using the sprite space UV

In C#, set the atlas offset & scale information to e.g., `_AtlasPosition`:

```
public void UpdateMask(Texture tex)
{
    //Debug.LogFormat("UpdateMask {0}", tex);
    m_SRenderer.GetPropertyBlock(m_SpriteMbp);
    m_SpriteMbp.SetTexture("_Mask", tex);
    Vector4 result = new Vector4(sprite.textureRect.position.x, sprite.textureRect.position.y, sprite.textureRect.size.x, sprite.textureRect.size.y)

    m_SpriteMbp.SetVector("_AtlasPosition", result)
    m_SRenderer.SetPropertyBlock(m_SpriteMbp);
}
```

In shader, calculate the current UV in sprite space, and use it to sample from `_Mask`:

```
fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR
{
    fixed4 mainTex = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
    // multiply both the position offset and size by the texel size to bring them into UV space
    float4 atlasOffsetScale = _AtlasPosition * _MainTex_TexelSize.xyxy;
    // apply UV position offset and scale, sample from alpha mask
    fixed4 alphaMask = tex2D(_Mask, (IN.texcoord - atlasOffsetScale.xy) / atlasOffsetScale.zw) * IN.color; 
    fixed4 output;
    fixed4 blendColor;
    // ...
```

You'll have to declare `_MainTex_TexelSize` in your shader if you haven't already.

This will not work if you are using tight packing. For Sprite Packer, you will need to specify `DefaultPackerPolicy` in the sprite packer or specify [RECT] in the packing tag. If you are using `SpriteAtlas`, you will need to disable `Tight Packing`.

Code sourced from [this thread on the unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/access-and-use-texturecoordinate-in-shader.499502/)

Comment: I can't get sprite's textureRect. When I try to get it I get exception:

>UnityException: Sprite is not rectangle-packed. TextureRect is invalid.
UnityEngine.Sprite.get_textureRect () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/SpritesBindings.gen.cs:152)
TestAtlas.Start () (at Assets/TestAtlas.cs:14)

This question is related to new Unity sprite atlases. 

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteAtlas.html

Comment: Thanks. You'll need to specify `DefaultPackerPolicy` in the sprite packer or specify `[RECT]` in the packing tag. I've edited my answer to include that part.

Comment: This is not about Sprite Packer. This is about SpriteAtlas-class from Unity 2017+.

Comment: @SergiyKlimkov In that case, disable `Tight Packing` for that atlas.

Comment: Thank you! Look like it is a solution. Packing density is less then when "tight" is enabled, but it is works.